# Need to run a regression 1000 times

Tags: r, replicate

I have a regression function called reg. I now need to run it 1000 times , capture the Rsquare value and t-stat in a histogram.

I tried running replicate as follows ( have taken n=5, to see results):

```
replicate(5,{
  seriese=matrix( rnorm(100*1,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 1) 
  e <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 100) 
  for(i in 1:100){
    e[i] <- sum(seriese[1:i,1]) 
  } 
  dataY <- cbind(seriese, e) 
  seriesa=matrix( rnorm(100*1,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 1) 
  x <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 100) 
  for(i in 1:100){ 
    x[i] <- sum(seriesa[1:i,1]) 
  }
  dataX <- cbind(seriesa, x) 
  #convert to ts
  dataYTS=ts(dataY[,2]) 
  dataXTS=ts(dataX[,2]) 
  #run regression 
  #check summary regression 
  reg=lm(dataYTS~dataXTS) 
},simplify=FALSE)
```

This reports the type of data, not the values.

```
replicate(5,{reg=lm(dataYTS~dataXTS)})
              [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]       
coefficients  Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2  
residuals     Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100
effects       Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100
rank          2           2           2           2           2          
fitted.values Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100 Numeric,100
assign        Integer,2   Integer,2   Integer,2   Integer,2   Integer,2  
qr            List,5      List,5      List,5      List,5      List,5     
df.residual   98          98          98          98          98         
xlevels       List,0      List,0      List,0      List,0      List,0     
call          Expression  Expression  Expression  Expression  Expression 
terms         Expression  Expression  Expression  Expression  Expression 
model         List,2      List,2      List,2      List,2      List,2
```

Comment: What is the point to run 1000 times the **same** regression? You will get 1000 times the same result.

Comment: Try `replicate(5,{reg=lm(dataYTS~dataXTS)}, simplify=FALSE)`  assuming that you are `sampling` the dataset.

Comment: Agree with @Pascal, need to run a complete process. How do I record the Rsqaure which is provided by the regression function after replicating 1000 times.

Comment: @akrun, your suggestion is giving me the same output as before

Comment: As I said before, you may need some sampling.  My code is to get the result in a `list` rather than the format you showed.  Without any reproducible example, it is hard to understand what is going on.

Comment: @akrun, here is the code I ran : replicate(5,{seriese=matrix( rnorm(100*1,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 1)
+ e <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 100)
+ for(i in 1:100){
+     e[i] <- sum(seriese[1:i,1])
+ }
+ dataY <- cbind(seriese, e)
+ 
+ 
+ 
+ seriesa=matrix( rnorm(100*1,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 1)
+ x <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 100)
+ for(i in 1:100){
+     x[i] <- sum(seriesa[1:i,1])
+ }
+ dataX <- cbind(seriesa, x)
+ 
+ 
+ #convert to ts
+ dataYTS=ts(dataY[,2])
+ dataXTS=ts(dataX[,2])
+ 
+ #run regression
+ #check summary regression
+ 
+ reg=lm(dataYTS~dataXTS)
+ },simplify=FALSE)

Comment: Please update that in your post.

Comment: Could you kindly update your post with the lines you added in comment?

Comment: That's a mighty inefficient way of calculating what `cumsum` would give you in there. Anyway, your code returns model objects. Iterate over them to calculate R-squared and the t-table or calculate and return them in your `replicate` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R-squared value is not part of the list that `lm` returns. To get that you need to extract the relevant leaf from the `summary.lm` list:

```
Rsq.vec <- replicate(5,{
  seriese=matrix( rnorm(100*1,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 1) 
  e <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 100) 
  for(i in 1:100){
    e[i] <- sum(seriese[1:i,1]) 
  } 
  dataY <- cbind(seriese, e) 
  seriesa=matrix( rnorm(100*1,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 1) 
  x <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 100) 
  for(i in 1:100){ 
    x[i] <- sum(seriesa[1:i,1]) 
  }
  dataX <- cbind(seriesa, x) 
  dataYTS=ts(dataY[,2]) 
  dataXTS=ts(dataX[,2]) 
  summary(lm(dataYTS~dataXTS) )$r.squared
}, simplify=TRUE)
```

You can then do `hist` on that object. You say you want the 't-stat', but that request is unclear since there are multiple t-statistics even in that simple model. Perhaps you want the t-statistic for the second coefficient?, the t-statistic for the predictor variable. That could be also found using `summary`. The `$coefficients` leaf of that list is a matrix. Read the help page for `summary.lm` and it should be a simple modification of the code above.

Comment: this code worked very well. How do I create a table with all 5 values of RSquared and Coefficients of the predictor variable. I tried creating a new variable, but that reports only one value.

Comment: You can use `cbind` to put together the r-squared and t-statistics. On a couple of numeric vectors it will return a matrix which is close to an R table object. Then you can assign row names and column names.

Comment: I tried summary.lm(dataYTS~dataXTS)$r.squared, but get an error as follows - Error in if (p == 0) { : argument is of length zero, @BondedDust

Comment: @ BondedDust, @Roland I also tried: Rep100 <- replicate(5,{
  seriese=matrix( rnorm(100*1,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 1) 
  e <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 100) 
  for(i in 1:100){
    e[i] <- sum(seriese[1:i,1]) 
  } 
  dataY <- cbind(seriese, e) 
  seriesa=matrix( rnorm(100*1,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 1) 
  x <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 100) 
  for(i in 1:100){ 
    x[i] <- sum(seriesa[1:i,1]) 
  }
  dataX <- cbind(seriesa, x) 
  dataYTS=ts(dataY[,2]) 
  dataXTS=ts(dataX[,2]) 
  reg=(lm(dataYTS~dataXTS))
  summaryr=(reg$r.squared)
  summaryc=(reg$r.coefficients)
  RT=cbind(summaryr,summaryc)

}, simplify=TRUE)

Comment: I am stuck since I dont know how to summarize the required values from the objects.

Comment: The output shows that you have a matrix of lists. The code worked. You are failing to understand how to look at the values. Assign the value returned from `replicate(5,{reg=lm(dataYTS~dataXTS)})` to a symbols such as `results` and look at `results[1,1]`.

Comment: i modified the code to  Rsq.vec <- replicate(5,{
     seriese=matrix( rnorm(100*1,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 1) 
     e <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 100) 
     for(i in 1:100){
         e[i] <- sum(seriese[1:i,1]) 
     } 
     dataY <- cbind(seriese, e) 
     seriesa=matrix( rnorm(100*1,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 1) 
     x <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 100) 
     for(i in 1:100){ 
         x[i] <- sum(seriesa[1:i,1]) 
     }
     dataX <- cbind(seriesa, x) 
     dataYTS=ts(dataY[,2]) 
     dataXTS=ts(dataX[,2]) 
     reg=(lm(dataYTS~dataXTS) )
     summary=summary(Rsq.vec)
 }, simplify=TRUE)

Comment: an example of 1/5 results that i get are all 5 value are same. Objective is to replicate the process 5 times and get 5 different results.

Comment: I was not getting "5 identical results", whatever that means. Pasting code into comments is not an effective method since the line feeds are lost and the pattern of flow of data through the code cannot be seen. I got 5 different models when I took out the `summary` step and access the matrix result with `[,]`